# SQLite – Issue with reusing values from the SELECT clause in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Let's say I have the following SQLite query where I compute the sum of two products' prices:

`SELECT p1.cost + p2.cost FROM products as p1, products as p2 WHERE p1.cost + p2.cost < 100;`

It's a bit inefficient to write `p1.cost + p2.cost` in both the SELECT clause and the WHERE clause, so we could fix it like this:

`SELECT p1.cost + p2.cost AS total FROM products as p1, products as p2 WHERE total < 100;`

Now let's say that I want to name the column in the query result "cost" instead of "total". Attempting to do that would result in this query:

`SELECT p1.cost + p2.cost AS cost FROM products as p1, products as p2 WHERE cost < 100;`

However, this results in an "ambiguous column name" error, since SQLite can't determine whether the "cost" in the WHERE clause refers to p1.cost, p2.cost, or the "cost" created in the SELECT clause. How do I make it clear that I'm attempting to select the "cost" created in the SELECT clause?

Comment: SQL in general does not support using column aliases in the `WHERE` clause.  Repeat the expression.

Answer (score 1):

The best you could do is a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT p12.*
FROM (SELECT p1.id as id1, p2.id as id2, p1.cost + p2.cost AS total
      FROM products p1 CROSS JOIN
           products p2
     ) p12
WHERE total < 100;
```

Column aliases defined in a `SELECT` are not permitted in the `WHERE` or `ON` clauses for that `SELECT`.  Period.  This is true of all database engines, including SQLite.